# Compare two array of objects based on their id's

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to compare two arrays of objects based on their IDs and return a `boolean`. I have filtered out items from the both arrays based on `is_selected === 1`. If `IDs` of both arrays are same will return `isModified` false or it will return true.

Both of these are an array of checkboxes. The initial array is what I am getting from the backend and the current is modified by the user. The current array length can be changed by changing checkboxes.

With my current approach for loop is not executing from the second time.

```
function cancel() {
    const initialArr = [
       {id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 9, name: "Crustaceans", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
    ];
    const currentArr = [
       {id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 4, name: "Mustard", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
    ];

    let isModified!: boolean;

    for (let index = 0; index < currentArr.length; index++) {
        const id = currentArr[index].id;
        isModified = initialArr.some((o2) => o2.id !== id);
        if (isModified) break;
    }

    if(isModified){
        alert('are you sure?');
    } else {
       console.log('exit the page');
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by loop is not executing from second time ?

Comment: @sairaj, the foor loop. `const id = currentArr[index].id;` it is always returning same id on every time

Comment: I don't get it. Why using a second array of items to store the checkbox state?

Comment: I got what you are trying to do, first put a check if the both array lengths are equal or not if it is not then immediately assign isModified to false

Comment: I ran your code and `const id = currentArr[index].id;` is different on each iteration. Your code working well!

Comment: I have tried with length, saved items id's are 8,9,2,6 now if I change it to 8, 9, 2, 5 then length will remain same but items are modified. Different from the initial one

Comment: yes after confirming that the lengths are same then apply the logic  of seeing if the id is same or not, instead of for loop use filter and check the length of the resultant array, is the array length returned by filter is > 1 then use has changed so set `isModified=true` else `false`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, it is always returning true

Comment: use this one: `isModified = !initialArr.some((o2) => o2.id === id);` and check my answer for more information. Also you forgot `,` at the end of objects in both array and I correct them in your question

Comment: I guess its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no issue with the for loop in your code. There are few changes that you could do to improve it

- Use a map instead of an array for faster lookups. Running an iteration on array everytime is slow, and it will only increase as the size of arr grows.
- Check-in each iteration if the value is changed in the currentArr.

You also need to establish what will happen when there is a new item in the currentArr(i.e with new id), will it be counted as modified or as not modified?

Assuming the answer to the above question is yes, the below code should work

```js
function cancel() {
    const initialArr = [
       {id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 9, name: "Crustaceans", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
    ];
    const initalArrMap = initialArr.reduce((prev, current) => {
      return {...prev, [current.id]: current}
    }, {});
    const currentArr = [
       {id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 9, name: "Mustard", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 9, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
    ];

    let isModified = currentArr.length !== initialArr.length;

    if(!isModified){
      for (let index = 0; index < currentArr.length; index++) {
        const id = currentArr[index].id;
        isModified = initalArrMap[id] ? initalArrMap[id].is_selected != currentArr[index].is_selected : true;
        if (isModified) break;
      }
    }

    if(isModified){
        alert('are you sure?');
    } else {
       console.log('exit the page');
    }
}

cancel();
```

Note: I am only checking if `is_selected` is changed to determine if the currentArr is changed.

Edit: Added a check in case `currentArr` and `initialArr` length are not equal

Answer (score 0):

1. It will compare each element of first array with all elements of 2nd array
2. sorting key will make sure it gives correct result if sequence of keys are changed .
3. it will break the loop as soon as it finds the first different object.

```js
function cancel() {
    const a = [
       {id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 9, name: "Crustaceans", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
    ];
    const b = [
       {id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 4, name: "Mustard", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1},
       {id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1},
    ];

    let isModified;
   let ctr =0;
    for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
      for(let j=0; j<b.length; j++){
       var aKeys = Object.keys(a[index]).sort();
       var bKeys = Object.keys(b[j]).sort();
       if(aKeys.toString()!== bKeys.toString()){
         ctr++;
         break;
       }
      }
    }

    if(ctr){
        alert('Modified');
    } else {
       console.log('not modified');
    }
}
cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was returning true for every item in the array is not because of logic error but syntax error, check your array of Objects they don't have commas that separate array elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using `initialArr.some((o2) => o2.id !== id)`.

> The `some()` method tests whether **at least one** element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false.

What do you want to check? If `initialArr` does not have `currentArr` ids, it means my `currentArr` is modified, so you need to try this one:

```
!initialArr.some((o2) => o2.id === id)
```

```js
const initialArr = [
    { id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1 },
    { id: 9, name: "Crustaceans", is_selected: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1 },
    { id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1 }
];
const currentArr = [
    { id: 8, name: "Celery", is_selected: 1 },
    { id: 4, name: "Mustard", is_selected: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Eggs", is_selected: 1 },
    { id: 6, name: "Fish", is_selected: 1 }
];

let isModified = false;

for (let index = 0; index < currentArr.length; index++) {
    const id = currentArr[index].id;
    isModified = !initialArr.some((o2) => o2.id === id);
    if (isModified)
        break;
}

if (isModified) {
    alert('are you sure?');
} else {
    console.log('exit the page');
}
```